# how do i build logic for query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have two tables named student and qualification.
I inserted the data in student table.
Now i want to insert data in qualification table based on id generated in student table.
I tried to write my queries in such a way

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO student (name,fathername,degreetitle)
VALUES ('$name','$fathername','$degreetitle')";

$sql_combine = "SELECT user_id FROM student WHERE fathername = $fathername";

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO information (user_id,cell,email)
VALUES ('$sql_combine','$cell','$email')";


if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql) && mysqli_query($conn, $sql1) && mysqli_query($conn, $sql_combine))
{

    header("Location: successful_message.php");

}
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: You're assuming all of your queries are working. What do your error logs say?

Comment: it's not giving any error.
It's simply adds data in both tables but against separate ids.

Comment: I think what you are looking for ist [last_insert_id()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) - which returns the ID of the last insert.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann
i have tried that too but did not find desired result

Comment: @FranzGleichmann
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);  
$sql_combine = "SELECT user_id FROM student WHERE  user_id =$last_id AND fathername = $fathername";

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO information (user_id,cell,email)
VALUES ('$sql_combine','$cell','$email')";

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add new information.

Comment: ok. i just tried to make him understand that i have already done the step, he was talking about

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql1 ="INSERT INTO student (name,fathername,degreetitle)
VALUES ('$name','$fathername','$degreetitle')";
$sql2 = "SELECT last_insert_id() as id";

mysqli_query($conn, $sql1); //here you insert
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2); //here you fetch the ID you inserted
$id = mysqli_fetch_array($res)['id'];

$sql3 = "INSERT INTO information (user_id,cell,email)
VALUES ('$id','$cell','$email')"; //here you use that said ID in your second query
mysqli_query($conn, $sql3); //aaand you insert
```

as i said: last_insert_id() to the rescue

Comment: still data saving in tables against different ids. The same result that i have found before :(

Comment: is your table `student` set to have an auto_increment ID? maybe you should post your table structure, because except the missing auto_increment, i can't imagine any possibility where last_insert_id() would fail

Comment: yeah !
Both tables have auto- increment IDs.

Comment: what should i do  next?

Comment: okay. then REMOVE the auto_increment from information. it's useless there, since you don't want it to have its own ID but reference `student`s ID. and don't forget to trim your development tables every once in a while

Comment: Excuse me sir.
Almost issue has resolved but there is a little problem yet.
Each record is saving against only 0 id number. I mean id number is not changing. ?

Comment: could you perhaps add your table layout to your original post?

Comment: sorry , i did not understand ..?

Answer (score 0):

You need a new column in your information table for the id field from the student table. As @Franz pointed out you should use last_insert_id() to get the value, then include it in the insert into the information table. That is how you link the two tables.

Comment: i have column named user_id in db

Comment: see my last answer to @Franz

Comment: You don't need a select after the mysqli_insert_id(). Just use the value it returns. What are your column types?